# RecyclerView leaks in FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I've figured out that in defined concatenation of circumstances RecyclerView leads to memory leak. To archive such effect, I have created FragmentPagerAdapter that contains fragment with RecyclerView as child. 
In case of going application to background or finishing, leak canary fires memory leak alert. Here's my activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    List<Fragment> fragments = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        fragments.add(CustomFragment.newInstance(i));
    }

    mViewPager.setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), fragments));
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0, false);
}

  public class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }
  }
}
```

To get the leak, RecyclerView even doesn't need to be initialized. If I comment it in xml file, the leak isn't fired

```
public class CustomFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String POSITION = "position";

public static CustomFragment newInstance(int position) {
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt(POSITION, position);
    CustomFragment fragment = new CustomFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(b);
    return fragment;
}

private int position;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    position = getArguments().getInt(POSITION);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_custom, container, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
    textView.setText("Position: "+position);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.pulse_recyclerview);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    RefWatcher refWatcher = CustomApplication.getRefWatcher(getActivity());
    refWatcher.watch(this);
  }
}
```

Here's leak trace. RecyclerView version 23.1.1

```
In com.example.gabin.sampleapplication:1.0:1.
* LEAK CAN BE IGNORED.
* com.example.gabin.sampleapplication.MainActivity has leaked:
* GC ROOT static android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.sInstance
* references android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mCurRootView
* references com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.mContext
* leaks com.example.gabin.sampleapplication.MainActivity instance
* Retaining: 3,9 КБ.
* Reference Key: 67c5e9f4-464e-40c3-b21d-d802fe64a84b
* Device: LGE google Nexus 4 occam
* Android Version: 5.1.1 API: 22 LeakCanary: 1.4-beta1 02804f3
* Durations: watch=5035ms, gc=190ms, heap dump=5948ms, analysis=46384ms
```

May it be an Android bug?
Please, give any idea how to fix the leak, or help me figure out the reason of its firing by leakcanary.

Answer (score 1):

Your stack trace shows at least two things:

1. It is not RecyclerView who leaks activity. It is the ImputMethodManager.
2. [LEAK CAN BE IGNORED](https://github.com/square/leakcanary#my-leak-is-caused-by-the-android-sdk-implementation). According to Leak Canary docs it is a known sdk problem. But I don't think its really an activity leak. If you check your memory dump you will not see several activity instances. Code looks pretty safe at now.

Comment: How can I prevent such leak to be fired by leakcanary?

Comment: There is an issue about this [problem](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/418). All I can suggest — subscribe to notifications and wait:)